# Android: How to wait for a thread to stop without hanging the application

Tags: android, multithreading, wait

I want to know in Android, how can I wait for a thread to stop without hanging the application?

Here are my testcase codes:

```
 public class MyFirstOperation extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do stuff that takes time
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

MyFirstOperation OP1=new MyFirstOperation();
OP1.start();
```

if I write OP1.Join() to wait for the thread to stop, the application will hang.
How can I make it not hang?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into AsyncTask: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `AsycTask` will ensure that your code runs in another thread, and the result is safely return to the GUI event loop thread. The most modern approach (if you need the thread to work safely across `Activity` lifecycle restarts) is to use a `Loader` with a `LoaderManager`.